# Drop down menu doesn't work in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, menu

The index.php page of [this site](http://www.constechne.com.br) just doesn't work. The dropdown menu under "Produtos" keeps disappearing. It works fine in Chrome, though.

I think it is because of the supersized jQuery function in the home page, because when I try to separate the pictures at the top menu in different div it works. But I need the photos to be in the backgroud, and the drop menu should work. How can I manage this? Thanks.

Comment: at least give some code

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the padding between the menu and the submenu. I believe it's because IE10 sees the gap and interprets that as mouseout.

[image]

Comment: There's some information abou the IE compatbility in the CSS file, where should I change it??

Comment: There's some information abou the IE compatbility in the CSS file, where should I change it??   <br>

Comment: ul.dropdown                         { position: relative; list-style:none; }
  ul.dropdown li                      { float: left; zoom: 1; margin-left:7px; margin-right:7px;}
  ul.dropdown a:hover              { color: #FFF; }
  ul.dropdown a:active                { color: #ffa500; }
  ul.dropdown li a                    { display: block; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px; color: #666; text-decoration:none;}

Comment: ul.dropdown li:last-child a         { border-right: none; } /* Doesn't work in IE */
  ul.dropdown li.hover,
  ul.dropdown li:hover                { background: #000; color: #FFF; position: relative; }
  ul.dropdown li.hover a              { color: #FFF; }

Comment: The site is Http://www.constechne.com.br

Comment: It worked removing the margin between the blocks, but I would like it to be sepparated because it looks better, but for now the issue is resolved.

Comment: Maybe adding z-index to the menu could work, since it only seems to be glitchy with the supersized plugin in action

Comment: I googled it , tryed to put z-index:0 and z-index:!important in .topo_menu but it didn't work. But it is fine with no space between the menus, thanks.

Comment: z-index needs to be the highest possible for the menu to be on top of everything else. Try adding z-index:999 for the menu instead. Also, if my answer worked for you, please accept it.